# laravel nested foreach for 3 levels

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, response

I am working on an api which i need to return data as follows.

```
{
  "Gamelist": {
    "MarketList": {
      "SelectionList": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I use following methods

```
        $eventId = 1;
        $sportId = 1;
        $leagueId = 1;

        $events = $this->baseEvents->filterEventsBy($sportId, $eventId, $leagueId);

        //get all the markets for events
        $eventMarkets = $this->baseMarkets->getAllMarketsByEventId($events->pluck('s_base_event_id'));

        //get all the selections for market
        $marketSelections = $this->baseSelections->getAllSelectionsByMarketId($eventMarkets->pluck('s_base_market_id'));
```

This project has relationship like this. one game has many markets.one market has many selections. I need to get these as above json format. How can I do that? I am using following foreach structure.

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
        $markets = $eventMarkets->where('s_base_event_id', $event->s_base_event_id);
        foreach ($markets as $market) {
            $selections = $marketSelections->where('s_base_market_id', $market->s_base_market_id);
            foreach($selections as $selection){

            }
        }
    }
```

Requested functions

```
public function filterEventsBy($sportId = null, $eventId = null, $leagueId = null){
        $events = $this->model->join('sports_base_rounds', 'sports_base_rounds.s_base_round_id', '=', 'sports_base_events.s_base_round_id')
            ->join('sports_base_seasons', 'sports_base_rounds.s_base_season_id', '=', 'sports_base_seasons.s_base_season_id')
            ->join('sports_base_leagues', 'sports_base_seasons.s_base_league_id', '=', 'sports_base_leagues.s_base_league_id')
            ->join('sports_base_regions', 'sports_base_regions.s_base_region_id', '=', 'sports_base_leagues.s_base_region_id')
            ->join('sports_base_sports', 'sports_base_sports.s_base_sport_id', '=', 'sports_base_leagues.s_base_sport_id');

        if ($sportId)
            $events->where('sports_base_sports.s_base_sport_id', $sportId);

        if ($leagueId)
            $events->where('sports_base_leagues.s_base_league_id', $leagueId);

        if ($eventId)
            $events->where('s_base_event_id', $eventId);
        else
            $events->where('s_base_event_start_time', '>', Carbon::now());

        return $events->get();
    }



    public function getAllSelectionsByMarketId($marketId){
            $selections = $this->model->whereIn('s_base_market_id', $marketId)
                ->get();

            if(!$selections) return null;

            return $selections;
        }




    public function getAllMarketsByEventId($eventId){
            $markets = $this->model->whereIn('s_base_event_id', $eventId)
                ->get();

            if(!$markets) return null;

            return $markets;

        }
```

Comment: You might want this json format:
`{[ {[ {[], ...}, ... ]}, ... ]}`

Comment: If you are having relationships cant you call them in the game list query itself ..
It's slightly confusing .. can you give more info please .. Events and gamelist are separate?

Comment: Can you show relationships as well as the code for `filterEventsBy`, `getAllMarketsByEventId` and `getAllSelectionsByMarketId`?

Comment: @RossWilson I edited the questions with requested functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting your array data, try this

```
$data = [];

$eventId = 1;
$sportId = 1;
$leagueId = 1;

$events = $this->baseEvents->filterEventsBy($sportId, $eventId, $leagueId);

//get all the markets for events
$eventMarkets = $this->baseMarkets->getAllMarketsByEventId($events->pluck('s_base_event_id'));

//get all the selections for market
$marketSelections = $this->baseSelections->getAllSelectionsByMarketId($eventMarkets->pluck('s_base_market_id'));

foreach($events as $index => $event){
    forach($eventMarkets as $indx => $market){
        foreach($marketSelections as $section){
            if($section->s_base_market_id == $market->id && $market->s_base_event_id == $event->id){
              $data['GameList'][$index]['MarketList'][$indx]['SelectionList'][] = $section->toArray();
            }
        }
    }
}

$jsonData = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I added how I fetch the data. Fetching data is fine. It gives me the correct data.